# append values from one text file to another text file

Tags: shell, awk

Hii experts i have a small text file saved in `input.txt` and it is as below

```
sel all
sel m:all
seada FITOISY1.ASCII
mrite tmp1 all
!read tmp1 all
get/file all rrrrr 27-NOV-2020_00:00:00.000
mbt sadfile MATU.LOC
get/file all hapyness 
get/file all mention syn
get/file all pmoc r
get/file all abc 32.5
get/file all def 70.8
mrite FITOISY1 all


sel all
sel m:all
seada FITOISY2.ASCII
mrite tmp2 all
!read tmp2 all
get/file all rrrrr 27-NOV-2020_00:00:00.000
mbt sadfile MATU.LOC
get/file all hapyness 
get/file all mention syn
get/file all pmoc r
get/file all abc 32.5
get/file all def 70.8
mrite FITOISY2 all


sel all
sel m:all
seada FITOISY3.ASCII
mrite tmp3 all
!read tmp3 all
get/file all rrrrr 27-NOV-2020_00:00:00.000
mbt sadfile MATU.LOC
get/file all hapyness 
get/file all mention syn
get/file all pmoc r
get/file all abc 32.5
get/file all def 70.8
mrite FITOISY3 all
```

and i want to write some values for `hapyness` in above  from another text file `values.txt` and the text file is

```
>
3.88499999
>
4.02930021
>
4.17359972
>
```

and my expectd output would be

```
    sel all
    sel m:all
    seada FITOISY1.ASCII
    mrite tmp1 all
    !read tmp1 all
    get/file all rrrrr 27-NOV-2020_00:00:00.000
    mbt sadfile MATU.LOC
    get/file all hapyness 3.88499999
    get/file all mention syn
    get/file all pmoc r
    get/file all abc 32.5
    get/file all def 70.8
    mrite FITOISY1 all
    
    
    sel all
    sel m:all
    seada FITOISY2.ASCII
    mrite tmp2 all
    !read tmp2 all
    get/file all rrrrr 27-NOV-2020_00:00:00.000
    mbt sadfile MATU.LOC
    get/file all hapyness 4.02930021
    get/file all mention syn
    get/file all pmoc r
    get/file all abc 32.5
    get/file all def 70.8
    mrite FITOISY2 all
    
    
    sel all
    sel m:all
    seada FITOISY3.ASCII
    mrite tmp3 all
    !read tmp3 all
    get/file all rrrrr 27-NOV-2020_00:00:00.000
    mbt sadfile MATU.LOC
    get/file all hapyness 4.17359972
    get/file all mention syn
    get/file all pmoc r
    get/file all abc 32.5
    get/file all def 70.8
    mrite FITOISY3 all
```

i tried the code as below but not able to do properly,hope experts will help me.Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/sh
while readline `cat input.txt`
do
cat input.txt | grep < values.txt
```

---

*Original Data In Question, Now Superseded*

**input.txt**

```
a.sh  21
b.ah  25
c.sh

a.sh  24
b.ah  12
c.sh

a.sh  45
b.ah  95
c.sh

a.sh  20
b.ah  11
c.sh

a.sh  21
b.ah  12
c.sh

a.sh  23
b.ah  41
c.sh
```

**values.txt**

```
>
14
>
22
>
43
>
96
>
45
>
61
```

**Original Requested Output**

```
a.sh  21
b.ah  25
c.sh  14

a.sh  24
b.ah  12
c.sh  22

a.sh  45
b.ah  95
c.sh  43

a.sh  20
b.ah  11
c.sh  96

a.sh  21
b.ah  12
c.sh  45

a.sh  23
b.ah  41
c.sh  61
```

Comment: Your files `values.txt` and `input.txt` have radically changed since you originally posted your question. Do not delete text from your question. If you need to make changes, **ADD** the changes below your original. Otherwise all comments and answers made before you changed the files will no longer make sense.

Comment: I second David sir here, please revert your question to old one and you could take answers from here for your requirement and could play around with them for your requirement and could open a new one after sometime(with your efforts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach in `awk` stores the numbers from `values.txt` in array `a[]`, then for the second file, if only one field, add value from `a[]` and increment index (if there are more records with only 1-field in `input.txt`, then use the last value in `values.txt` repetitively.

```
awk -v n=1 '                                        # set n=1
    FNR==NR && /^[0-9]/ {                           # 1st file & line starts [0-9]
        a[++i]=$1                                   # store value in a
        next                                        # skip to next record
    }
    NR>FNR && NF==1 {                               # 2nd file, only 1 field
        $0=$0""((n in a) ? a[n++] : a[i])           # add value from array
    }
    NR>FNR                                          # 2nd file, print record
' values.txt input.txt
```

**Example Use/Output**

You can just select-copy and middle-mouse paste into an xterm with the files in the current working directory and would get:

```
$ awk -v n=1 '                                        # set n=1
>     FNR==NR && /^[0-9]/ {                           # 1st file & line starts [0-9]
>         a[++i]=$1                                   # store value in a
>         next                                        # skip to next record
>     }
>     NR>FNR && NF==1 {                               # 2nd file, only 1 field
>         $0=$0""((n in a) ? a[n++] : a[i])           # add value from array
>     }
>     NR>FNR                                          # 2nd file, print record
> ' values.txt input.txt
a.sh  21
b.ah  25
c.sh  14

a.sh  24
b.ah  12
c.sh  22

a.sh  45
b.ah  95
c.sh  43

a.sh  20
b.ah  11
c.sh  96

a.sh  21
b.ah  12
c.sh  45

a.sh  23
b.ah  41
c.sh  61
```

If there are an unequal number of values from `values.txt` and records with 1-field in `input.txt` and you want to leave the value empty for any additional `c.sh` records, you can simply do:

```
            $0=$0""((n in a) ? a[n++] : "")           # add value from array
```

(always better to cover yourself one way or the other)

---

**After Input Files Changed**

The changing of the input files complicated things a bit, not too much, but took a bit to sort it out. If I have it correct, the following will do:

```
awk -v n="1" -v need="1" '                          # set n=1 and need flag
    FNR==NR && /^[0-9]/ {                           # 1st file & line starts [0-9]
        a[++i]=$1                                   # store value in a
        next                                        # skip to next record
    }
    NR>FNR && need > 0 && /^get\/file/ {       # 2nd file, need flag, ^get/file
        if (need++ == 2) {
            $0=$0""((n in a) ? a[n++] : a[i])       # add value from array
            need=0                                  # set need flag false
        }
    }
    NR>FNR && NF==0 {                               # 2nd file & blank line
        need=1                                      # set need flag true
    }
    NR>FNR                                          # 2nd file, print record
' values.txt input.txt
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk -v n="1" -v need="1" '                          # set n=1 and need flag
>     FNR==NR && /^[0-9]/ {                           # 1st file & line starts [0-9]
>         a[++i]=$1                                   # store value in a
>         next                                        # skip to next record
>     }
>     NR>FNR && need > 0 && /^get\/file/ {       # 2nd file, need flag, ^get/file
>         if (need++ == 2) {
>             $0=$0""((n in a) ? a[n++] : a[i])       # add value from array
>             need=0                                  # set need flag false
>         }
>     }
>     NR>FNR && NF==0 {                               # 2nd file & blank line
>         need=1                                      # set need flag true
>     }
>     NR>FNR                                          # 2nd file, print record
> ' values.txt input.txt
sel all
sel m:all
seada FITOISY1.ASCII
mrite tmp1 all
!read tmp1 all
get/file all rrrrr 27-NOV-2020_00:00:00.000
mbt sadfile MATU.LOC
get/file all hapyness 3.88499999
get/file all mention syn
get/file all pmoc r
get/file all abc 32.5
get/file all def 70.8
mrite FITOISY1 all


sel all
sel m:all
seada FITOISY2.ASCII
mrite tmp2 all
!read tmp2 all
get/file all rrrrr 27-NOV-2020_00:00:00.000
mbt sadfile MATU.LOC
get/file all hapyness 4.02930021
get/file all mention syn
get/file all pmoc r
get/file all abc 32.5
get/file all def 70.8
mrite FITOISY2 all


sel all
sel m:all
seada FITOISY3.ASCII
mrite tmp3 all
!read tmp3 all
get/file all rrrrr 27-NOV-2020_00:00:00.000
mbt sadfile MATU.LOC
get/file all hapyness 4.17359972
get/file all mention syn
get/file all pmoc r
get/file all abc 32.5
get/file all def 70.8
mrite FITOISY3 all
```

Comment: Thank you sir , cheers and merry x-mas :)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin ur code is working very fine....Thanks for ur support

Comment: You are welcome and a merry x-mas to all, and to all a good night `:)`

Answer (score 3):

***EDIT:*** With OP's newly edited samples, one could try following.

```
awk -v count3="1" '
FNR==NR{
  if($0~/^>/){
    count2=""
    count1++
    next
  }
  value[count1 OFS count2++]=$0
  next
}
!NF{
  count4=""
  count3++
  print
  next
}
/hapyness/{
  print $0,value[count3 OFS count4++]
  next
}
1
' values.txt input.txt
```

---

---

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v count3="1" '
FNR==NR{
  if($0~/^>/){
    count2=""
    count1++
    next
  }
  value[count1 OFS count2++]=$0
  next
}
!NF{
  count4=""
  count3++
  print
  next
}
NF<2{
  print $0,value[count3 OFS count4++]
  next
}
1
' values.txt input.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v count3="1" '                      ##Starting awk program from here and setting count3 as 1 here.
FNR==NR{                                 ##Checking FNR==NR which will be TRUE when values.txt is being read. 
  if($0~/^>/){                           ##Checking condition if line starts with > then do following.
    count2=""                            ##Nullify count2 variable here.
    count1++                             ##Increase count1 with 1 here.
    next                                 ##next will skip all further statements from here.
  }
  value[count1 OFS count2++]=$0          ##Creating value array with count1 OFS count2(with increasing count by 1) and its value is current line.
  next                                   ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
!NF{                                     ##If line is an empty line then do following.
  count4=""                              ##Nullify count4 here.
  count3++                               ##Imcrease count3 with 1 here.
  print                                  ##Printing current line here.
  next                                   ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
NF<2{                                    ##Checking if number of fields is lesser than 2 then do following.
  print $0,value[count3 OFS count4++]    ##Printing current line with value of array value.
  next                                   ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
1                                        ##will print the current line.
' values.txt input.txt                   ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: @lijun, Answers on stack overflow are always given as per shown samples only. Plus I had considered one case already(which was not mentioned) if there are more than 1 rows under `>`(single block) and wants to be inserted in other file it will work. Now if your actual file is NOT same as shown samples we can't help it without knowing how your actual file looks like because our solutions will be written as per shown samples only. Please do let me know how its not working in detailed manner.

Comment: @lijun, this is not clear please do let me know more clearly which file is you are talking about? Kindly do add more details.

Comment: @lijun Update your question with a sample that *is more than four block* so that Ravinder can amend his answer. I don't think this question deserves those downvotes by the way, if you edit it properly I will upvote to compensate for them.

Comment: I'll see you an `awk` and raise you an `awk`!

Comment: @lijun, Hey, I tried my code with your edited samples it still works fine for me. Looks like you have control M characters in your files. Could you please do check by using `cat -v values.txt` and `cat -v input.txt` if you find them then we could delete them, let me know if you see them because solution is working fine with your new samples too, cheers.

Comment: now i updated my original input and the expected output where after the line get/file all hapyness i want to appen the values from values.txt...please have a look can it be solves @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @lijun, oh no, this is totally completely different from your initial/base question, moreover your Logic of getting expected output is also not clear. I would like to request you to please revert your changes to your question, reason being this new changes are completely different from your base question. This will create confusions to answerers and future readers too if we keep changing questions and answers. You could take inspiration from these answers and could try something and then could open a new question, please revert your changes in your question.

Comment: According to the input please update the code..hope u will not get angry and this is final

Comment: @lijun, Please don't think I am angry, but its not good to change your questions requirements completely, please revert your changes in this question and open a new one with putting your efforts, trust me it creates lots of confusions to change questions completely from base question, its my kind advise and request, please don't take me in wrong way, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: @lijun, Please try my EDIT code once? It worked for me for shown samples.

Comment: No its not working @RavinderSingh13 it is taking 1st(3.88499999) and third values(4.17359972) and skipping second(4.02930021) values

Comment: @lijun, it basically looks for line `hapyness` and inserts line there, which I thought you want?

Comment: already hapyness is there still it doesnot work

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code.

```
#!/bin/sh

cnt=0
while read line;
do
    if [ $line != '>' ]
    then
        cnt=$(( $cnt + 1 ))
        tmp="c.sh  ""$line"
        sed -z -i "s/c.sh/$tmp/$cnt" input.txt
    fi
done < 'values.txt'
```

(*directly operates on file, not optimized)

Comment: Probably try http://shellcheck.net/ to shake out various beginner problems. Running `sed -i` on the same file repeatedly in a loop is basically never a good idea.